# `const`ness, referencing and function calling

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, reference

```
class Foo{};

class BarParent
{
    Foo* p_foo;

    public:
    BarParent(Foo * const p_x) //OR BarParent(Foo const * x) OR BarParent(Foo * x)
                             //OR (Foo const * const x)
    {
        p_foo = x;
    }
};


class BarChild: public BarParent
{
    public:
    BarChild(const Foo& x)
    : BarParent(& x){}
};
```

What I intend is to: point to `x` with `p_foo` when using the `BarChild` ctor. Is there a way to do so.

I have tried all possible signatures for the `BarParent` ctor with no luck.

***Summary:*** For some reason I was confusing the fact that assigning a (pointer to a non `const` object) to (pointer to a `const` object) break the `const` restriction.

Comment: You should make `p_foo` a `Foo const*`.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `p_foo` or `x`? If you mean to modify it, you need to pass in a non-const pointer. If not, you need to make `p_foo` `const`

Comment: @AndyProwl in my application it is not, and can be changed by other functions

Comment: @maditya tried all 4 functions with no luck. `p_foo` is not a `const` in my use-case

Comment: @aiao So why are you taking a `const Foo&` in the `BarChild` constructor? It should just be a `Foo&`.

Comment: @sftrabbit I only want to take its reference and NOT edit it.

Comment: @aiao But you're assigning its address to a non-`const` pointer, which is allowing it to be edited. Either the pointer should be `const` or you should be taking a `Foo&`.

Comment: I have tried `Foo * const p_foo;` instead of `Foo* p_foo;` (line 5) still does not work. I have changed the ctor accordingly. still not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I present you with two alternatives:

1. Either you really do want the `BarChild` constructor to take a `const Foo&`, in which case you need to uphold your promise that you will never allow the `Foo` object to be modified. To do this, both `p_x` and `p_foo` need to be `const Foo*` (that is, pointers to `const Foo`). If it were a pointer to a non-`const` `Foo`, you would be effectively allowing the object to be modified, breaking your promise.

   ```
   class BarParent
   {
       const Foo* p_foo;

       public:
       BarParent(const Foo* p_x)
       {
           p_foo = x;
       }
   };
   ```
2. Alternatively, you really do want to keep a `Foo*` rather than a `const Foo*`, and so the `BarChild` constructor should be taking a `Foo&` instead of a `const Foo&`. This way, you're not lying about keeping the object `const`.

   ```
   class BarChild: public BarParent
   {
       public:
       BarChild(Foo& x)
       : BarParent(& x){}
   };
   ```

Comment: Could you please provide a good resource about const. And please explain how to write 1- pointer to `const`, 2- `const` pointer to mutable, 3- `const` pointer to `const` object

Comment: @aiao The rule: the `const` applies to whatever is to the left of it, unless there is nothing, in which case it applies to the right. So `int* const` is "const pointer to int", and both `int const*` and `const int*` are "pointer to const int".

Answer (score 2):

You are misunderstanding what a `const Foo&` is.

A `const Foo&` is an alias or reference to a variable through which you can never cause it to be modified (without using `const_cast` or C-style casting).  It isn't merely a promise to not modify it "right now", but it is also a promise that everyone you tell about this variable won't modify it as well.

If you want to store a pointer to this data to modify it later, you should not be taking it as a `const Foo&`, but rather a `Foo&`.

So to fix your code, rewrite `BarChild` as follows:

```
class Foo{};

class BarParent
{
  Foo* p_foo;

  public:
    BarParent(Foo * p_x):
      p_foo(p_x)
    {}
};

class BarChild: public BarParent
{
  public:
  BarChild(Foo& x):
    BarParent(& x)
  {}
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can cast away the const-ness with `const_cast`:

```
p_foo = const_cast<Foo *>x;
```

But this is generally a **Bad Idea**, for two reasons:

- The whole point of const-correctness is to document/enforce certain expectations about who can modify what.  `const_cast` subverts that.
- In some situations, you may even unleash **undefined behaviour** (namely, modifying an underlying object that really is `const` via a non-`const` pointer).

In general, find a way to avoid needing to do this in the first place (I can't make any concrete suggestions, as I don't know what your use-case is).